# Another term for "accounts payable"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'd like to know the term that's used to describe a list of payables that a company needs to pay at the end of the month (or any specific period)? "Accounts payable" seems to be tad technical. I'd like to know if there are other words for it.

Comment: *bills*, *invoices*

Comment: @drew But aren't invoices more on those items that a company needs to receive (e.g. Company A sent an invoice to Company B so that they'll pay Company A for the services rendered) rather than what the Company A needs to pay?

Comment: _Payments due_ would be a less jargony expression.

Comment: The term you need is *trade creditors*, or simply *creditors*. That was the slightly more old fashioned way of saying *accounts payable* by accountants. In the same way *trade debtors* became *accounts receivable*. I speak as a retired accountant who saw much change in the lifetime of my career.

Answer (score 1):

Some others, for what it's worth:

- **Expenses**
- **Overhead**
- **Monthly Outlay**
- **Expenditures**

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=Expenses&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

From 'businessdictionary.com':

**invoice**:

A nonnegotiable commercial instrument issued by a seller to a buyer. It identifies both the trading parties and lists, describes, and quantifies the items sold, shows the date of shipment and mode of transport, prices and discounts (if any), and delivery and payment terms.

In certain cases (especially when it is signed by the seller or seller's agent), an invoice serves as a demand for payment and becomes a document of title when paid in full. Types of invoice include commercial invoice, consular invoice, customs invoice, and pro forma invoice. Also called a bill of sale or contract of sale.

**account statement**:

General: Summary of all transactions with a customer or a supplier that occurred over the previous month, quarter, etc., and their effect on an open-account balance. Also called a statement of account.

Read more: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/account-statement.html

Read more: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/invoice.html

Comment: But aren't invoices more on those items that a company needs to receive (e.g. Company A sent an invoice to Company B so that they'll pay Company A for the services rendered) rather than what the Company A needs to pay?

Comment: Yes, if company A sends an invoice to company B, the company B should pay to the company A and vice versa. If the full payment is not done, the remaining is 'arrears' that B should pay to A or A should receive from B.